# Intercept SMS Messages in iOS 6 Jailbroken iPhone With Thoes/Logos

Tags: iphone, security, ios6, sms, jailbreak

I'm trying to intercept text messages from my iphone using the hooking method via theos. I've tried hooking on to various headers in the ChatKit framework and using methods explained around the web, but many of the methods are for the older OS, and there are included different headers in iOS 6's ChatKit framework.

I'm just wondering if anyone has had any success with intercepting SMS using theos/logos on the iOS 6 firmware. If so, which headers should I be looking into or what methods should I try? I've already gone through many of the headers and methods, but still have had no success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I'm doing this because I have multiple phones and would like to forward all my incoming and outgoing texts to those phones. There's probably software that already does that, but I'm sort of a DIY type of person and this is another opportunity for me to learn something new :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Look at this question (it has the answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680764/ios-jailbreak-how-do-intercept-sms-text-messages

Comment: Just a comment on the link Victor provided ... the **accepted** answer to that question used to work, but as of iOS 5, it no longer works to actually get the *content* of the SMS messages.  The answer [I provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11028115/119114), however, does ... I haven't run it yet on iOS 6, but it worked on iOS 5.

Comment: thanks for your comments, but I guess iOS 6 is using a different method in sending/receiving messages as the header files "CKSMSService.h" and "CKMadridService.h" are no longer found in the iOS 6 ChatKit Framework. I've also tested almost every method in the CoreTelephony and the new ChatKit Frameworks and still nothing is working.

Comment: I also encountered this problem, bofore ios 6.o, I hook SMSCTServer - (void)_ingestIncomingCTMessage:(id)message to do the work, but iOS 6 abandon the class. Do you find the solution now?

Comment: Do you get the solution for IOS 6, If Yes then please share it with us Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I used CTTelephonyAddObserver to catch the event SMS received, but I don't know how to delete sms on SMS.DB