# ios validate via sms like in android

Tags: ios, validation, sms

I would like to know how can we validate a customers mobile number in iOS like we do in andorid using the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver?

Situation would be that the app will request the server to send a SMS and that will arrive in the messages inbox and the app will read it to validate the user using the same mobile number as given during registration.

Looking forward for assistance !

Regards, 
Shoeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to intercept SMS in iOS. You will have to change the workflow to include manual input i.e. send SMS containing unique code to user provided number, ask user to input the unique code, validate the code.

In the off chance you're working in a JB environment, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680764/ios-jailbreak-how-do-intercept-sms-text-messages) might help.

Comment: ok Thanks a lot of the explanation and helping with the approach. Definitely not JB devices.