# Received SMS intercept on jailbreak iPhone

Tags: ios7, xcode5, jailbreak

How to intercept SMS Messages in iOS 7. I have followed this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680764/ios-jailbreak-how-do-intercept-sms-text-messages) .

It just gives me notification on received SMS but do not give me SMS content. I want to read SMS content and perform some operations based on it. I m using iOS 7.0.6 with Xcode 5. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out my answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219799/block-sms-on-ios6/ Try both of them. I didn't test the accepted one on iOS 7.x. I use the second one in my projects, still works on iOS 7.x. Gives you notification when message is received so that you could read it contents and even delete it without user noticing.

Comment: @creker The userInfo doesn't contains key "__kIMChatItemsKey". it just has these two key value pairs  kCTMessageIdKey = "-2147483617";
kCTMessageTypeKey = 1;

Comment: My second answer there works on iOS 7.